# Unexpected behavior of (contoller/function/parameter) in Codeigniter 3.2

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have tried many ways to minimise the issue but none worked.

Whenever I pass any variable as URL segment (`contoller/function/parameter`) The view starts loading multiple times just Like a loop. But when I pass the parameters as query string `controller/function?param=value` (it works fine) So this is the only way I can get around.

Can't seem to find a valid reason. Tried by removing `.htaccess` file too.
Also tried with all possibilities of following:

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

I only want the parameter as URL segment and not as query string. Please help with what else I try to fix this.

Comment: Sounds like you have a redirect that's causing the looping.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw no redirect. As to what I am able to final after couple of hours of error find, it appears that js was loading the page and it's causing the page to re-load. Not still sure to understand how it's possible and where in js/jquery I need to look for the problem. but after removing some of the js links from the pages it works fine.